# error creating bean name "springApplication"

Tags: spring-boot

Below are errors while I just deploy on tomcat server. I don't really know why it works well on IntelliJ without any errors.
I see it's "Error creating bean with name 'springApplication'", and I really still don't understand why.

```
.   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.6.RELEASE)

2018-12-02 18:39:56.348  INFO 11699 --- [           main] com.rdc.business.BusinessApplication     : Starting BusinessApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on chhunly-Inspiron-5559 with PID 11699 (/home/chhunly/eclipse-workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/business/WEB-INF/classes started by chhunly in /home/chhunly/eclipse/jee-2018-09/eclipse)
2018-12-02 18:39:56.353  INFO 11699 --- [           main] com.rdc.business.BusinessApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-12-02 18:39:56.392  INFO 11699 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@7b21cec3: startup date [Sun Dec 02 18:39:56 ICT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-12-02 18:39:56.681  INFO 11699 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[.[localhost].[/business]      : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-12-02 18:39:56.682  INFO 11699 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 290 ms
2018-12-02 18:39:56.775  INFO 11699 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
2018-12-02 18:39:56.787  WARN 11699 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springApplication': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>()
2018-12-02 18:39:56.802 ERROR 11699 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springApplication': Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:535) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:495) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:759) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:548) ~[spring-context-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:386) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:157) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:137) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:91) [spring-boot-2.0.6.RELEASE.jar:2.0.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:172) [spring-web-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5098) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:839) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1429) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1419) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75) [tomcat-util.jar:9.0.12]
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134) [na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:944) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:261) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:422) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:770) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:682) [catalina.jar:9.0.12]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.12]
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492) [bootstrap.jar:9.0.12]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>()
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:83) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1220) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    ... 47 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:78) ~[spring-beans-5.0.10.RELEASE.jar:5.0.10.RELEASE]
    ... 48 common frames omitted
```

And these are my dependency that I use with that project. I really don't know why how errors occurs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.rdc</groupId>
    <artifactId>business</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>business</name>
    <description>RDCMS Project</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-rest-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
            <artifactId>aws-java-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.163</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

**anybody pls help with for this trouble.**

And this is my application

```
package com.rdc.business;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

import java.util.Collections;

@EnableResourceServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class BusinessApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(SpringApplication.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BusinessApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean simpleCorsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }
}

public class ServletInitializer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(BusinessApplication.class);
    }

}
```

Comment: Do you have an 'Application' class with @SpringBootApplication? Add this class to your question.

Comment: "Make sure all Spring libraries have the exact same version in the project." 
   https://www.baeldung.com/spring-beancreationexception  4.3

Comment: Yeah, I have added the class, pls help checking it

Comment: Please, see my answer, I've tested and it worked with tomcat server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the **tomcat 8.5.35** server and a **SpringBoot** clean project.

I have adjusted the "clean project" with your project's structure and have seen the problem occurring in tomcat server.

Then I've made some modifications into your *BusinessApplication* (removed the 'configure' method of the class) and *pom.xml*.

BusinessApplication:

```
package com.rdc.business;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableResourceServer;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter;

import java.util.Collections;

@EnableResourceServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class BusinessApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BusinessApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean simpleCorsFilter() {
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

See an example of it running with **tomcat 8.5.35**:

https://github.com/thiagochagas/example-tomcat

Comment: Ok let me test that